# asp.net how to check if the user is on a particular page?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

i want to add code to check if a user is on default.aspx in the master page _load event.

how can i check in the master page if the page being requested is default.aspx?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check `Request.Url.LocalPath` which should either be "/default.aspx" or "/".

```
if (string.Compare(Request.Url.LocalPath,"/default.aspx") == 0 || string.Compare(Request.Url.LocalPath,"/") == 0)
{
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to test type of Page property in Master. eg:

```
public partial class DefaultMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        if(this.Page is DefaultPage) {
            ...
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for

```
Request.Url


string currentUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.LocalPath;

if(currentUrl.EndsWith("default.aspx") || currentUrl.EndsWith("/"))
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: This will get default.aspx in any subfolder. But won't work if the user just types on the domain name like "http://www.example.com".

Answer (score 0):

I'll use

```
if (Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath == "~/"
    || string.Equals(Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath, "~/default.aspx", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    // ....
}
```

**Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath** will ignore your localhost, local host file mapping, or virtual directory name and return the file path relative to your web site, while **Request.Url.LocalPath** still includes virtual directory.